# How To Add .fadeIn() to an Error Message Coming From An External Source

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm learning super beginner javascript in a class. Our professor had us connect to a server he created using Ruby On Rails that verified whether an e-mail was correctly or incorrectly formatted, it was our assignment to make sure, using javascript, that a validation and an error message was shown to the user based on what they entered into the input.

While I've successfully done this, I ran into a formatting issue.

The error message itself comes directly from the server. I want to format this error message so that, like the validation message, the error message fades in when shown to the user `.fadeIn()`

However, no matter where I place `.fadeIn()` it doesn't seem to effect the error message, and only either takes away the error message completely, or does nothing to it entirely.

Is there a specific place it should be put for it to work? Does formatting a message from an external server require a separate implementation entirely? And can it still be formatted even though I don't have access to the server?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    
    $('form').submit(function(event) {

        var formData = $(this).serialize();
      
        $.ajax({
            type         : 'POST',
            url          : 'https://web2-product-page.herokuapp.com/subscribers', 
            data         : formData, 
            dataType     : 'json' 
        }).done(function(data) {

                console.log(data);
                $('.confirmation').fadeIn();
                $('.error-message').text("");
                $('input[name=email]').val("");
            }).fail(function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                var errorMessage = JSON.parse(data.responseText).email[0];
                $('.error-message').text(errorMessage);
                $('.confirmation').hide();
            });
    
        event.preventDefault();
    });    
});
```

Comment: Well you never fadeIn() the error message - merely the confirmation. Probably put it on the fail() after setting the $(.error-message).text()

Comment: Oh okay! So that's a javascript standard then? I guess because I have the error message and validation message formatted to look the same it seems weird to me when I'm looking at one fade in and not the other.

Comment: Please post the complete code, also the HTML, and if possible a jsfiddle link with your code for people to be able to run the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following for the `fadeIn` effect:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

    $('form').submit(function(event) {

        var formData = $(this).serialize();

        $.ajax({
            type         : 'POST',
            url          : 'https://web2-product-page.herokuapp.com/subscribers', 
            data         : formData, 
            dataType     : 'json' 
        }).done(function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                $('.confirmation').fadeIn();
                $('.error-message').text("");
                $('input[name=email]').val("");
            }).fail(function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                var errorMessage = JSON.parse(data.responseText).email[0];
                $('.error-message').text(errorMessage).hide().fadeIn();
                $('.confirmation').hide();
            });

        event.preventDefault();
    });    
});
```

Comment: Thank you! So that's how you incorporate it! Thank you so much for this helpful information.

Comment: Yes. For the `fadeIn` effect to be incorporated, the element should be invisible on the page. Hence, the `hide()`.